# Jersey 2 MVC - form data binding

Tags: model-view-controller, data-binding, java-8, jersey-2.0, forms, http-post

I am building an MVC application using Jersey 2.26 and Java 8.

I would like to know if there is a way to bind form data to a POJO, much like you do in Spring, so that I could have something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/edit")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED })
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Viewable editInventory(Inventory inventory) {
    ....
}
```

I know you can bind individual primitives by using @FormParam("paramName"), but this is tedious as my post payload contains over a dozen attributes.
I have tried searching for docs and examples but can only find solutions for JSON and XML payloads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you should consume `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`, and if want also to response with that object you should add an annotation of `javax.xml.bind.annotation.@XmlRootElement` on Inventory class.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can use the @BeanParam annotation in conjuntion with the @FormParam annotation.

https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2482

Helps if I actually read through the docs properly!

EDIT - as per peacetype's comment, example code below

```
//model
public class Inventory {

    @FormParam("inventoryName")
    private String inventoryName;
}

//controller
@Path("inventory")
public class InventoryController {

    @POST
    @Path("/new")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response newInventory(@Valid @BeanParam Inventory Inventory) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You should post the portion of the code that helped you into your answer so it might help others.